# ios app custom navigation bar with search and button action with show menu views above button with below design

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

[image: custom navigation bar with search and buttons]

[image: click menu button to show menu options]

[click search options while click search bar on menu][3]

I need below questions to proceed:

1. is this possible to create custom navigation bar with search bar and buttons or use container view for navigation bar?
2. check 1st and 2nd image. when click button on navigation bar view added on above button menu. how to show this menu? use view or viewcontroller add subview in each viewcontroller? I have confusions on proceed show menu view. because we have push viewcontoller from menu selection from current viewcontroller.

Comment: I think you are missing the third picture

Comment: you are missing third picture and yes we can create custom search bar and button on navigationbar